# How to create file links on a vfat filesystem of a mounted disk under Linux?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, hard-link, vfat

I have an external drive containing different pieces of music. The drive is a vfat formatted drive to be able to work with arbitrary devices.

On the device I have music stored from different artists sorted according to their name. However, I would like to sort the single music pieces into other folders as well, without duplicating them. So, for example, the title 'Addicted to you' should be accessible from within a folder 'Avicii' but also from a different folder named e.g. 'dance'.

Is there a way I can create some kind of link on the disk? I have tried to do this with `ln` but got an error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link
ln: failed to create hard link
```

Is there another way to link those files? And to make sure it works with EVERY USB hardware (radio, TV, media set, car radio, ...)?

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly create a directory of links to your music in the structure you've described, if it's anything but a FAT filesystem, but FAT doesn't support links, so you'd have to create Windows LNK files (aka shortcuts).

**NOTE:** Incidentally you may be able to create LNK files using either of these tools. These tools are described as: [allowing you to create Windows Shortcut files (extension .LNK) without needing a Windows OS.](http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/index.en.html)

But often it's better to create play list files and leave the music in some standardized structure or as a single sub-directory with other sub-directories within it.

To organize the MP3 headers you can use MusicBrainz's tool [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) to make sure the ID3 tags are all up to date on your collection.

There are many tools such as [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/) for constructing playlists. It's discussed here in this AU Q&A titled: [Need a playlist creator for linux that will do relative paths](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169193/need-a-playlist-creator-for-linux-that-will-do-relative-paths).

Comment: Does any tool work when I plug in the USB stick into any USB radio? Or into a TV media set? Or into a TV? Or something else...? Also, as far as I have seen, one cannot create links on a vfat device.

Comment: @Alex - you'd have to try, but that seems like a completely different Q.

Answer (score 3):

The VFAT filesystem doesn't have any file structure like Unix's hard links, and no symbolic links either.

Comment: So I am not able to create links or similar structures on a VFAT system?

Comment: @Alex, no. The filessytem doesn't handle the required entries.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, things must have changed. Raspberry Pi OS has its `/boot` partition set up as FAT32, and it most certainly has symlinks in it. I hate to do this to a 10 year-old answer, but -1. If you can explain or wish to edit, I'll remove the downvote.