# Creating Symbolic link in SMB share

Tags: symlink, smb

1. I am connecting to an SMB share, i have read and write permission. I am trying to create a sym link to a file outside the share, but i get the following error:
   ln: failed to create symbolic link '9' : permission denied
   I am able create normal files , i would glad to if you a have a solution for that.
2. Is there any option to create(Force it, i understand that it is not possible) sym link in Fat32 usb drive ?

Comment: In general you cannot. Probably you could use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131824/how-to-create-file-links-on-a-vfat-filesystem-of-a-mounted-disk-under-linux) to create some .LNKs but I guess not for "outside the share", whatever it could mean.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reasons, from the client, you can't have access to files outside of what the server is setup to share with you.

But if you have control over the SMB server, then you could set the `wide links = Yes` option in its config file. Not advisable though.